# Split function into 2 function for test coverage

Tags: go

How can I test the error for `ioutil.ReadAll(rep.Body)`? Do I need to split my function in two, one which will make the request, and another one which will read the body and return the bytes and error?

```
func fetchUrl(URL string) ([]bytes, error) {
  resp, err := http.Get(URL)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  resp.Body.Close()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return body, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to split my function in two, one which will make the request, and another one which will read the body and return the bytes and error?

The first one is called `http.Get` and the other one `ioutil.ReadAll`, so I don't think there's anything to split. You just created a function that uses two other functions together which you should assume are working correctly. You could even simplify your function to make it more obvious:

```
func fetchURL(URL string) ([]byte, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
}
```

If you want to test anything is your `fetchURL` function using `http.Get` and `ioutil.ReadAll` together. I wouldn't personally bother to test it directly, but if you insist on it, you can overwrite `http.DefaultTransport` for a single test and provide your own, which returns `http.Response` with body implementing some error scenarios (e.g. and error during body read).

Here is the sketch idea:

```
type BrokenTransport struct {
}

func (*BrokenTransport) RoundTrip(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // Return Response with Body implementing specific error behaviour
}

http.DefaultTransport = &BrokenTransport{}

// http.Get will now use your RoundTripper.
// You should probably restore http.DefaultTransport after the test.
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, unless you're using [`net/http/httptest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) or a similar way to mock your HTTP server when testing.

But the question is: what would you really be testing? That `ioutil.ReadAll()` detects errors? But I'm sure this was already covered by the test suite of the Go's stdlib.

Hence I'd say that in this particular case you're about to test for the testing's sake. IMO for such trivial cases it's better to concentrate on how the fetched result is further processed.